# Complex binding dilemma using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

To be frank, I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do is possible.  Still...

The basic scenario is this:  inside a foreach: loop, I'm rendering a checkbox, a label, and a drop-down, like this:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root.ClassDays">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.SCVM.EditingItem().AssignedDates" />
    <label data-bind="text: ClassDay"></label>
    <select data-bind="options: $data.ClassTimes, optionsCaption: 'Select',  value: $root.SCVM.EditingItem().AssignedDates().ClassTime"></select>
</li>
```

The ClassDays object is an array holding 7 `AssignedDate` objects, which look like this:

```
var AssignedDate = function (day) {
    this.AssignedId = 0;
    this.ScheduledClassID = 0;
    this.ClassDay = ko.observable(day || "");
    this.ClassTimes = ko.observableArray(["5:00 PM", "5:30 PM", "6:00 PM", "6:30 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:30 PM", "8:00 PM"])
    this.ClassTime = ko.observable("");
};
```

ClassDays is initialized thusly:

```
self.ClassDays = [
    new AssignedDate("Monday"),
    new AssignedDate("Tuesday"),
    new AssignedDate("Wednesday"),
    new AssignedDate("Thursday"),
    new AssignedDate("Friday"),
    new AssignedDate("Saturday"),
    new AssignedDate("Sunday")
];
```

My goal is to capture the "time" value whenever a "day" is selected.  My current implementation is adding an `AssignedDate` object to `$root.SCVM.EditingItem().AssignedDates` when a box gets checked, but the `ClassTime` property is never set.

**Edit:**

To clarify, the architecture of my page employs a viewmodel named SessionsViewModel and a child viewmodel names\d ScheduledClassViewModel.  The child VM is named SCVM.  Here is a (mostly) complete lsiting of the parent:

```
function SessionsViewModel(){
var self = this;
var hasErrors, strMessage, strErrMsg;
self.FailHandler = function (a, b, c) {
    alert(a.responseText);
};
self.MsgGood = ko.observable("");
self.MsgError = ko.observable("");
self.PageMode = ko.observable("");
self.AddSession = function () {
    self.SessionId(null);
    self.CurrentSession(new Session());
    self.PageMode("add");
    self.DetailsVisible(true);
    self.ClassesVisible(false);
};
self.SessionInfoGood = function () {

};
self.DoContinue = function () {
    if (!self.SessionInfoGood()) {
        self.MsgError(strErrMsg);
    }
    else {
        strErrMsg = "";
        self.MsgError("");
        self.ClassesVisible(true);
    }
};
self.DetailsVisible = ko.observable(false);
self.ClassesVisible = ko.observable(false);
self.ToggleDisplay = function () {
    $("#ClassDetails").toggle("blind", {}, 400);        
};
self.Sessions = ko.observableArray();
self.SessionId = ko.observable();
self.SessionId.subscribe(function (newval) {
    if (newval != null && typeof(newval) != "undefined")
    {

    }
});
self.CurrentSession = ko.observable(new Session());
self.GetSessions = function () {

};
self.ClassList = ko.observableArray();
self.CoachList = ko.observableArray();    
self.SCVM = new ScheduledClassViewModel(self);
self.ClassDays = ko.observableArray([
    new AssignedDate("Monday"),
    new AssignedDate("Tuesday"),
    new AssignedDate("Wednesday"),
    new AssignedDate("Thursday"),
    new AssignedDate("Friday"),
    new AssignedDate("Saturday"),
    new AssignedDate("Sunday")
]);
self.AddClass = function () {
    var sc = new ScheduledClass(new BaseClass());
    self.CurrentSession().AssignedClasses.push(sc);
    self.SCVM.SelectClass(sc, "Add");
};
```

}

and this is the child vm:

```
var ScheduledClassViewModel = function (parent) {
var self = this;
self.Mode = ko.observable("");
self.ValidationErrorMsg = ko.observable("");
self.ScheduledClass = ko.observable();
self.EditingItem = ko.observable(new ScheduledClass(new BaseClass()));
self.ShouldRemove = ko.observable(false);
self.Validate = function () {
    var isValid = true;

    return isValid;
};
self.Cancelling = ko.observable(false);
self.ClassList = parent.CurrentSession.AssignedClasses;
self.SelectClass = function (classdata, mode) {
    self.Cancelling(true);
    self.Mode(mode);
    self.ScheduledClass(classdata);
    var sc = ko.toJS(classdata);
    self.EditingItem(new ScheduledClass(sc));
    self.ShouldRemove(false);
    self.ValidationErrorMsg("");

};
self.SaveClass = function () {
    if (self.ShouldRemove())
    {
        self.ClassList.remove(self.ScheduledClass())
    }
    else {
        if (self.Validate())
        {
            var selected = self.ScheduledClass(), edited = ko.toJS(self.EditingItem());
            selected.Update(edited);
            self.ClassList.valueHasMutated();
            self.Cancelling(false);
            self.Mode("");
        }

    }
};
```

};

The goal is to get the selected ClassDay and ClassTime into the AssignedDates collection inside the child (identifed as $root.SCVM.EditingItem().AssignedDates in the html).  While the solution proposed by supercool does work, the data ends up in the parent vm and not the child vm.  If this is still not clear, please let me know and I will try again.

Comment: there is nothing in you current code about `ClassName`. Are you able to create a jsfiddle to replicate what is going wrong?

Comment: Second that comment, though be sure to post code for a full repro *in the question* too (or, instead of jsfiddle, use a Stack Snippet: it's on the editor bar). Note that you can edit your question to update it with more info.

Comment: Corrected my original post.  "ClassName" should have been "ClassTime".

Answer (score 0):

well i hope this is what you looking for i presume . I hope you can intrepet my code and do you bindings

**View**

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: ClassDays">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue:$data, checked:AssignedDates" />
            <label data-bind="text: ClassDay"></label>
            <select data-bind="options: $data.ClassTimes, optionsCaption: 'Select', value:ClassTime"></select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**View Model:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.ClassDays = ko.observableArray([
    new AssignedDate("Monday"),
    new AssignedDate("Tuesday"),
    new AssignedDate("Wednesday"),
    new AssignedDate("Thursday"),
    new AssignedDate("Friday"),
    new AssignedDate("Saturday"),
    new AssignedDate("Sunday")]);

}

var AssignedDate = function (day) {
    this.ClassDay = ko.observable(day || "");
    this.ClassTimes = ko.observableArray(["5:00 PM", "5:30 PM", "6:00 PM", "6:30 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:30 PM", "8:00 PM"])
    this.ClassTime = ko.observable("");
    this.AssignedDates = ko.observable(false);
};
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2tzah12e/)** with preview of changes

If something i'm missing let me know .

Comment: the fiddle link is broken.  But I will try your solution as quickly as I can.

Comment: if everything working please make it as answer and possible upvote lol someone can catch up  later . cheers

Comment: >@supercool - Your solution works, but doesn't quite solve my problem.  I editied my post to include some additional information.  The primary reason I can't accept your solution is that the data ends up in the wrong place.  I apologize if I didn't make this clear enough in my original post.

Comment: well there is lot of code with bits and pieces missing there to figure out. do me a favor i have a fiddle in my answer can you let me know how exactly you want my fiddle output to be . feel free to fork it . cheers

Comment: >@supercool Okay, I forked your fiddle and added enough code for you to see what I'm trying to do.  You can see it <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/btqqsjva/7/" title="example">here</a>.